# Is this correct "He should keep himself under a physician"?

Tags: grammar

My English teacher wrote that sentence and told me that it means "he should always keep in touch with a physician.Is it correct and if not then please explain why

Comment: I'd complete it with **'s care**. Plain *"keep oneself under a physician"* sounds, well... odd, to say the least.

Comment: It is unusual, but not wrong to say “He should keep himself under [the observation of] a physician.”

Comment: When I was a kid, people use to get a laugh by saying e.g. 'my wife has been under the doctor', which has a normal and a ribald meaning.

Comment: Yes - the expression existed, but has largely fallen out of use because of the scope for ribald misinterpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would normally say **under the care/supervision of a physician**.

Most people would understand the meaning of what your teacher wrote but it's unusual and might cause amusement among people who took it literally. I don't recommend it as a shortcut.